# Comprehension List and new File

Tags: python, list, file, swap

[Example of two text files. The left image is before, the right one is after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFQLD.png)

I need to swap the dates in one file and put it on a new file using comprehension lists. How would I do that? This is what I have:

```
list1 = [x.replace("\n","").replace("/"," ").split(" ") for x in open("dobA.txt")]
list2 = [(i[len(i)-2],i[len(i)-3]) for i in list1]
with open("dobB.txt", "w") as newfile:
        newfile.write()
```

The top line of code makes the dates into their own string, such as "10".

The second line of code swaps the numbers I need but only prints out:
[('11', '10'), ('8', '9'), ('9', '7')]

The last two are just writing a new file.

How would I swap these two numbers and put them on a new file? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, do this:

```
i[-2]
```

instead of

```
i[len(i)-2]
```

There are a couple of options to approach this:

Readable one without comprehensions:

```
with open("old_file.txt") as old_file, open("new_file.txt", "w") as new_file:
    for line in old_file:
        name, surname, date = line.split()
        day, month, year = date.split("/")
        print(f"{name} {surname} {month}/{day}/{year}", file=new_file)
```

Regex replace:

```
import re
from pathlib import Path

text = Path("old_file.txt").read_text()
replaced = re.sub(r"(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)", r"\2/\1/\3", text)
Path("new_file.txt").write_text(replaced)
```

If you really need comprehensions:

```
with open("old_file.txt") as old_file, open("new_file.txt", "w") as new_file:
    new_lines = [
        f"{text} {date.split('/')[1]}/{date.split('/')[0]}/{date.split('/')[2]}"
        for text, date in [line.rsplit(maxsplit=1) for line in old_file]
    ]
    print("\n".join(new_lines), file=new_file)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202496/discussion-on-answer-by-rafals-comprehension-list-and-new-file).

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to see if this could be done in one shot. It may defy "readability".

The simplest way to flip the month and day is to take advantage of the  [string formatting methods](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) on datetime objects.

See [Python strftime reference](http://strftime.org/) for formatting options.

```
from pathlib import Path
import tempfile
from datetime import datetime
import operator as op

# Create temporary files for reading and writing.
_, filename = tempfile.mkstemp()
file_A = Path(filename)
_, filename = tempfile.mkstemp()
file_B = Path(filename)

contents_A = """Adam Brown 10/11/1999
Lauren Marie Smith 9/8/2001
Vincent Guth II 7/9/1980"""
file_A.write_text(contents_A)

# This version requires Python 3.8. 
# It uses the newly introduced assignment expression ":=".
# datetime objects have string formatting methods.
file_B.write_text(
    "\n".join(# re-join the lines
        [
            " ".join(# re-join the words
                (
                    # Store the split line into words. Then slice all but last.
                    " ".join((words := line.split())[:-1]),
                    # Convert the last word to desired date format.
                    datetime.strptime(words[-1], "%m/%d/%Y",).strftime("%-d/%-m/%Y",),
                )
            )
            for line in fileA.read_text().splitlines()
        ]
    )
)
print(file_B.read_text())
```

OUTPUT:

> Adam Brown 11/10/1999
>
> Lauren Marie Smith 8/9/2001
>
> Vincent Guth II 9/7/1980

Without the ":=" operator it was a little more problematic. It means having to call `line.split()` twice in the comprehension.

```
file_B.write_text("\n".join([
    " ".join(
        op.add(
            line.split()[:-1],
            [
                datetime.strptime(
                    line.split()[-1], "%m/%d/%Y",
                ).strftime("%-d/%-m/%Y",),
            ],
        )
    )
    for line in fileA.read_text().splitlines()
]))

print(file_B.read_text())
```

OUTPUT:

> Adam Brown 11/10/1999
>
> Lauren Marie Smith 8/9/2001
>
> Vincent Guth II 9/7/1980

Comment: sorry homie this is too complicaed, it should be done in like 5 lines of code

Comment: However you choose to write the comprehension, the point is to use datetime  string formatting methods.

Comment: I fixed the formatting. Why an arbitrary 5 lines of code? I did it in 1 expression.